# how to upload image in register API in strapi?

Tags: strapi

In defaut registration API, I need to uplaod the image of user in registration API. So how could I manage it ? I'm sending in a formData and it works fine. I can see `(binary)` in network.

I tried to add image field and it works in admin panel but from API side I tried to send the file in key names like `files`, `profileImage`.

I didn't get the error in res. I got success in res.

**Issue:** When I reload the admin panel, I didn't get user's profile image.

Comment: are you able to solve this issue?

Comment: As I have accepted the answer so please follow that answer.

Comment: You can check my code on github : https://github.com/victorray84/Strapi-Custom-Registration.It's working through Strapi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way. I used in react and it works fine for me.

```
signUpHandler = () => {
    console.log("SignUp data ::: ", this.state);
    let data = {
        username: this.state.signUpForm.username.value,
        phone: this.state.signUpForm.phone.value,
        email: this.state.signUpForm.email.value,
        password: this.state.signUpForm.password.value
    }
    axios.post('http://0.0.0.0:1337/auth/local/register', data)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.data.user.id;
    })
    .then(refId =>{
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('files', this.state.selectedFile);
        data.append('refId', refId);            
        data.append('ref', 'user');
        data.append('source', 'users-permissions');
        data.append('field', 'profileImage');
        return axios.post('http://0.0.0.0:1337/upload', data)            
    })
    .then(res =>{
        console.log(res);
        alert("You registered successfully...");
        this.props.history.push('/login');            
    })
    .catch(error =>{
        console.log(error);
    })                
}
```

Comment: No longer works for Strapi v4 as per https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/11957#issuecomment-1006524143

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Strapi v4:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer XXXX");

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("files", fileInput.files[0], "XXX.png");
formdata.append("refId", "46");
formdata.append("field", "image");
formdata.append("ref", "plugin::users-permissions.user");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/upload", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to customize your `user-permission`

To do so, you will have to understand this concept: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/customization.html

Then you will have to find the function you want to update - in your case, the register function.

And tada here it is https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js#L383.

So you will have to create `./extensions/users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js` with the same content as the original file.

Then you will have to add

```js
const { parseMultipartData, sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');
const uploadFiles = require('strapi/lib/core-api/utils/upload-files');
```

on the top of your file.

And in your function use this 
`const { data, files } = parseMultipartData(ctx);` to parse data and files.

Then you will have to replace `ctx.request.body` by `data` to make sure to use the correct data.

After that you will have to add this after the user creation line

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js#L510

```
if (files) {
      // automatically uploads the files based on the entry and the model
      await uploadFiles(user, files, { model: strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].models.user })
    }
```